# How can I solve FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path ='...' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, flutter, dart, multipart

I am trying to send a user model from dart to the api where my file is set as "IFormFile" data type in my c# backend.
I tried using the multipart request but all i get is the error stated , i can't understand why it cannot retrieve the length of file.

This is my code:

```
updateUser() async {
var uri = Uri.parse('http://myIP:8070/api/Users');
var request = http.MultipartRequest('Put', uri);
request.fields['id']="07bb2a17-7cd5-471b-973a-4b77d239b6c3";
request.fields['username']="beeso";
request.fields['email']="jake-username2@gmail.com";
request.fields['password']="Jake123-";
request.fields["oldPassword"]="Jake124-";
request.fields["gender"]="Male";
request.fields["dateOfBirth"]=DateTime.now().toString();
request.fields["name"]="dsjnss";
request.fields["languages"]=["Language1","Language2"].toString();
request.fields["nationalities"]=["Nationality1","Nationality2"].toString();
request.fields["phoneNumber"]="70502030";
request.fields["biography"]="jdnknkdas";
request.fields["info"]="asndasnkdas";
request.fields["religion"]="Christian";
request.fields["location"]="LA";
File imageFile = new File('Anatomy_of_a_Sunset-2.jpg');
var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
var length = await imageFile.length();
var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
    filename: basename(imageFile.path));
request.files.add(multipartFile);
Map<String, String> headers = {
  "content-type": "application/json"
};

request.headers.addAll(headers);
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
print(response.statusCode);


}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[This picture shows where my file is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTQi3.png)

Comment: 1 - your content type isn't JSON, (it's multipart), so omit that header. 2 - there's another name constructor for MultipartFile that is better when expecting a file - it will save you two or three lines. 3 - the error message is telling you that the file "Anatomy..." doesn't exist. It must be in a different folder or called a different name. Where is it?

Comment: Alright, I changed it to "content-type": "multipart/form-data" now, the Anatomy file is in the same directory as pubspec.yaml (beside it), and regarding the constructor i tried a lot and many were giving errors i didn't know how to fix that's why i sticked to it. @RichardHeap

Comment: Is this a dart app? Or a flutter app? If the latter, you can access files like that. You'd need to move it to assets and load it. As is easier to test this in a pure dart app, create a new project. If you didn't already, download the dart SDK (2.7.1) and point your ide's dart plugin to it.

Comment: It is a flutter app, i added a link to my post to see where the file is located. I also tried previously adding an assets folder that is shown in the screenshot and adding the file instead it. Following that i loaded it from the pubspec.yaml file and had it as new File('assets/Anatomy_of_a_Sunset-2.jpg'); but still the same error. @RichardHeap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Flutter, you can't access files directly from the project. You need to add them to an assets folder (typically `assets`) and also to `pubspec.yaml`. Then, instead of using `File` to read them, you use `rootBundle` (or one of the `Asset` classes).

```
var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
  'file',
  (await rootBundle.load('assets/anatomy.jpg')).buffer.asUint8List(),
  filename: 'anatomy.jpg', // use the real name if available, or omit
  contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg'),
);

request.files.add(multipartFile);
```

While testing your API, you may find it easier to just create a Dart command line project, where you do have access to `File`s in the project folders.

Comment: I got this now :415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format. I have the profilePicture as IFormFile in my c# backend

Comment: Get it working using Postman first (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895523/asp-core-webapi-test-file-upload-using-postman etc). Then update the question with a screenshot of the working Postman request.

Comment: Is there Anu way I can send no file in it and still pass the file field in it.When I am passing null in the parameter it's giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

my case was image uploading problem and I solved it by using
`xfile.path` that image picker returned

```dart
XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.gallery,
            imageQuality: 50,
            maxHeight: 500,
            maxWidth: 500);
```

#flutter
#dio