# How to give file path in Postman JSON [FromBody]?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Here is my JSON body

```
{
    "Id":"1",
    "Name":"Shekhar",
    "FormFile":@"C:\xyz\abc\test.txt"
}
```

Where "FormFile" is `IFormFile` in ASP.Net Core Web API, I am getting Null

Is it possible to send a file path like above?

Comment: that should be a string, type of `FormFile`

Comment: Check this post, for uploading files upsing postman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895523/asp-core-webapi-test-file-upload-using-postman.
Let me know if it helped

Comment: I have seen above link, I need to send [FromBody] its the Acceptance Criteria(Requirement). Because [FromForm] & [FromBody] combination is not working in Postman

Answer (score 0):

> Where "FormFile" is IFormFile in ASP.Net Core Web API, I am getting Null

The type of `FormFile` property is `IFormFile`, you could upload file through form data, like below.

[image]

Besides, if you really want to pass file via json payload, you can try to modify the type of `FormFile` property to `string`, then provide Base64-encoded file.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, however need to send like attachment, Encoded string not allowed